# Z-Transformation Function

Tags: signal, system, z-transform

I have a system given, which looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flLgry.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now I am task with giving the "difference-equation":

```
y(n) = x(n) -2*x(n-1) + x(n-2)
```

And determining the "Z-Transfer function":

```
y(z) = x(z) -2*x(z)*z^(-1) + x(z)*z^(-2)
H(z) = y(z)/x(z) = 1 -2*z^(-1) + z^(-2)
```

So far so good.

Now I am asked: Is the system stable? I would go with: Yes, as all Poles and all Zeros are within the unit-circle (e.g. smack in the center) -> Stable.

But where I am stuck is:

**Which type of filter does this system represent? (LP,BP,HB)**

I have no idea how to come up with a answer.

**EDIT 1:**

Had a coffee and now I came up with an answer.

The transfer function can be expanded to:

```
H(z)=(z+1)^2/(z^2)
```

Therefore both poles are at (0,0) and the zeros are at (-1,0).

"Walking the Unit-Circle" from (0,0) to (-1,0) via (0,1) therefore gives a "Lowpass" type, as the zeros "dampen" the amplitude of the transfer function.

**EDIT 2:**

Edit 1 was "not so correct" aka. BS ;)

See the answer below. This time it should be correct.

Comment: What are the three x parameters?

Comment: @Andyaka the x in the blocks are multiplications. So *1, *(-2), *1. Misread your question and deleted my previous comment.

Comment: They all add to zero so, what does that tell you about the output for a constant value input? And what does that mean regarding eliminating one of the options?

Comment: @Andyaka As the "T-Block" represents a time-delay they do not add to 0. BUt i solved it after drinking a coffe and formulating the question ;) Going to edit.

Comment: I did say a constant value input.

Comment: I think there you made a sign error here. the transfer function should be H(z) = (z-1)^2/(z^2)? You can simply evaluate your transfer function at two frequencies. At 0Hz z=1 and at the sampling frequency (fs) z=-1. If it is a lowpass filter, the gain of H(z) at 0Hz is 1 and at your sampling frequency it is 0. The opposite applies for the highpass filter. If both gains are 0, then it is probably a bandpass filter. You can also plot H(z) if you have the right tools ;)

Comment: @Mau5 I agree. Always the same ;) I am curious: What would be the right tools for a hobbyist wallet?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent There are no right or wrong tool. For examply GNU Octave or Python with suitable libraries such as numpy, scipy, and matplotlib can plot impulse and step responses and frequency response. It really depends what languages and tools you are familiar with and what kind of functionality they come with.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent I am a student and my university has a matlab license, so I am using matlab for stuff like this. I guess a popular alternative would be python, since it is free and provides a lot of functions that are very similar to matlab. A free alternative to matlab is octave. It feels like matlab and also has some dedicated signal processing functions. It's up to you :) Go and look for the function called "freqz". It has the same name in all of these programs and will plot you the bode diagram of a z-Domain transfer function.

Comment: @Mau5 Are you enrolled at ETH?

Comment: @Andyaka Now, reading it carefully, i get your hint. Thank you and please excuse my stubborness.

Comment: My advice, is that if you have excel, you can see what the output is when the input is DC or AC. Excel (or a decent spreadsheet cost = zero usually).

Answer (score 0):

Had a coffee and now I came up with an answer.

The transfer function can be expanded to:

```
H(z)=(z+1)^2/(z^2)
```

Therefore both poles are at (0,0) and the zeros are at (-1,0).

"Walking the Unit-Circle" from (0,0) to (-1,0) via (0,1) therefore gives a "Lowpass" type, as the zeros "dampen" the amplitude of the transfer function.

**EDIT 1:**

As pointed out in the comments (Thank you!) there was a flaw in my math!

So this is the complete - and hopefully correct answer - now:
$$
y(n) = x(n) -2x(n-1) + x(n-2)
$$
$$
y(z) = x(z) -2x(z)z^{-1} + x(z)z^{-2}
$$
$$
H(z) = \frac{y(z)}{x(z)} = 1 - \frac{2}{z} + \frac{1}{z^2}
$$
$$
H(z) = \frac{(z-1)^2}{z^2}
$$

Therefore, both poles are at $$z=0$$ and both zeros are at $$z=1$$

So $$H(z=1) = 0 $$ and $$H(z=-1) = 4 $$

**This indicates a highpass system.**

So, when "running" the unit circle from $$\Omega=0 \rightarrow \Omega = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

One can expect a $$|H(\Omega)|$$ rising from $$ 0 \rightarrow 4 $$ as both poles do "not influence" the transfer function, as they are located at $$z=0$$

**This does show, that the system is highpass**

Comment: Looks like coffee did not help, still wrong. If you feed the system a constant DC of say +10, isn't the output a constant 0 after an impulse? Why is it a low pass if it does not pass low frequencies such as DC?

Comment: @Justme I agree.....Currently editing ;) Thank you!

Comment: Now I agree ;) There exists also a third option to evaluate the type of this filter. The structure of H(z) tells you that your filter is of type FIR. Now you can look at the symmetry of your coefficients (b0 = 1 b1 = -2 b2 = 1), which is considered as an "odd symmetry". The order of your FIR structure is 3, which is an "odd order". There are some classifications for FIR filters that will tell you something about their behavior. With an odd order and odd symmetry, you have a type IV FIR, which is always a high pass system.